# How to display JavaFX Composer view in NetBeans 7.1 RC1?

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, netbeans-7.1

I installed `JavaFX` and `NetBeans 7.1 RC1`. Started JavaFX project. Opened `Palette` view. In main window I have editor with source code. I need to open JavaFX Composer in order to build GUI. I couldn't find any JavaFX Composer in `Tools>Plugins`. How to display  JavaFX Composer view?

```
----------------
```

What (graphic) library uses JavaFX, is it swing? How to add JavaFX elements to display advanced graphic, for instance 3D objacts?

Comment: I find it out, i have to create in another package JFRAME or JPANEL file and then drag and drop needed elements form palette.

Comment: Note however, that JFrame and JPanel are Swing containers, not JavaFX containers.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no JavaFX 2.0 composer yet. It should be released early next year and probably won't be NetBeans based.

http://www-javafx.oracle.com/roadmap/

http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/press/512728

Comment: It goes along with javaFx sdk as far as i know

Comment: It depends if you want to create a JavaFX only application or if you want to embed some JavaFX components in a Swing application, I guess (I haven't tried).